# automatically click anchor tag link on jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, button, struts-1

I am having one tricky requirement. I am explaning through example

`abc.jsp` calls `xyj.jsp` and `xyj` has a **link** like `<a href="viewDetails.do">Click</a>`

My requirement is that when i run `abc.jsp` it calls to `xyz.jsp` and without showing `xyz.jsp` page it should call to struts action. It means i want to call to href of anchor tag internally.

Either link or buttun should be clicked internally through javascript so that it will call to struts action dynamically instead of go and click on link manually

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Friend You should use Jquery Method $('a[href="viewDetails.do"]').trigger('click');
It will do auto click. Thanks and let me know if you face any problem using this. Thanks

Comment: Hi Thank you very much. But can you please provide me sample code? Because till now i have not used JQuery anywhere.

Comment: My Friend Have a look on the following link. Official Jquery Trigger API : http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

On abc.jsp save some flag in cookies. On xyj.jsp lower the flag that was put high on abc.jsp and redirect to the link your anchor tag contains by jquery.